# Not able to send mail from php mail function using MAMP PRO

Tags: php, email, mamp

before few days i have been comfortably sending emails using PHP mail function. but few days back i switched my ISP. and since then i am not able to send any mails. i have setup the postfix configuration of outgoing mail to `gmail.com` and it gives me the following error in the log file.

```
   May  6 18:54:05 Ibrahim-Armars-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[1449]: connect to aspmx.l.google.com[74.125.53.27]:25: Operation timed out
    May  6 18:54:05 Ibrahim-Armars-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[1446]: connect to aspmx.l.google.com[74.125.53.27]:25: Operation timed out
    May  6 18:54:05 Ibrahim-Armars-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[1452]: connect to aspmx.l.google.com[74.125.53.27]:25: Operation timed out
    May  6 18:54:05 Ibrahim-Armars-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[1455]: connect to mx1.hotmail.com[65.55.92.184]:25: Operation timed out
    May  6 18:54:05 Ibrahim-Armars-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[1456]: connect to mx3.hotmail.com[65.55.92.136]:25: Operation timed out
    May  6 18:54:05 Ibrahim-Armars-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[1453]: connect to aspmx.l.google.com[74.125.53.27]:25: Operation timed out
    May  6 18:54:05 Ibrahim-Armars-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[1454]: connect to aspmx.l.google.com[74.125.53.27]:25: Operation timed out
May  6 18:56:05 Ibrahim-Armars-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[1454]: connect to aspmx3.googlemail.com[72.14.213.27]:25: Operation timed out
May  6 18:56:05 Ibrahim-Armars-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[1454]: warning: 11C203ECD84: defer service failure
May  6 18:56:05 Ibrahim-Armars-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[1454]: 11C203ECD84: to=<azhar@iarmar.com>, relay=none, delay=4504, delays=4353/0.13/150/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to aspmx3.googlemail.com[72.14.213.27]:25: Operation timed out)
May  6 18:56:05 Ibrahim-Armars-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[1454]: connect to aspmx3.googlemail.com[72.14.213.27]:25: Operation timed out
May  6 18:56:05 Ibrahim-Armars-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[1454]: warning: 11C203ECD84: defer service failure
May  6 18:56:05 Ibrahim-Armars-MacBook-Pro postfix/smtp[1454]: 11C203ECD84: to=<azhar@iarmar.com>, relay=none, delay=4504, delays=4353/0.13/150/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to aspmx3.googlemail.com[72.14.213.27]:25: Operation timed out)
```

what could be causing the problem? do you think it is my new ISP? i called there customer care and unfortunately they don't know about this. what would be the possible solution for me to send mail from php , i am using MAMP PRo 1.9.2.

Comment: It is quite possible that your ISP is blocking access to external SMTP servers, effectively forcing you to use their SMTP server to send mails. So try changing it so you use their smtp server to send mails.

Comment: and how do i use there smtp server? can't i setup my own SMTP server locally to work with MAMP? i am still a noob in all this.i would appreciate any kind of information

Comment: You just alter your postfix settings to use their SMTP server as relayhost (just like you did to use Gmail).

Comment: this wouldnt solve the problem, your local smtp server try to connect with the receivers smtp server which would then also be blocked from your isps firewall

Comment: @peaceman then should i be asking my ISP if they are blocking the port 25?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its very typical that ISP's that provide you with access to internet, will block any connections to port 25 to some other email server besides their own.

You should point your script to use your isp's smtp server to send emails out, not google's as your log files are pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

seems like there is some firewall which is blocking the connection

Comment: i am on mac, and firewall is disabled by default, i don't think this is the issue.

Comment: i meant a firewall from your isp not your local

Comment: okay, does this means my ISP may be blocking port 25 by default?